# Did backup to root accidentally, need to revert

Tags: backup, root, home-directory, restore

I recently reinstalled Ubuntu and upgraded to 15.04. I tried to restore from an earlier backup (using the default GUI software) but perplexingly, it didn't restore to my /home partition, but my root partition. Obviously that can't be good. It says there's "only 0 bytes left". I can't log in with the GUI now, only terminal works.

How do I:

a) revert the changes done to the root drive? Can I find a changelog showing what the backup did? I don't know the exact time I initiated the backup. I want everything done to undo with a minimum effort.

and

b) properly restore the files to the home directory, making sure I know how never to let this happen again?

I would REALLY prefer not to have to go through the reinstallation process once again. Thanks!

Comment: Also, it isn't a problem restoring a backup of a 14.10 file set to a 15.04 installation, is it?

Comment: Time to reevaluate your backup strategy I see =) A fresh install is almost certainly the way to go.

Comment: As an addition to above comment, look [here for a back-up strategy for 1 PC](http://askubuntu.com/questions/569679/whats-a-good-back-up-strategy-for-1-desktop-pc).  Doesn't help you now, but will help you in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Go find where all of the extra files got restored to and delete them.  The fact that you have no space points to you simply restoring the files in the wrong location and so you have duplicates everywhere.  For instance, if you backed up the whole system, but restored it to your home directory, then you have a copy of /bin, /usr, etc in ~/.

Comment: Ok, and how to use the backup/restore utility so that it DOESN'T do that again? I don't remember it having that many settings to configure. You'd think this would be a mistake Ubuntu would prevent users from making... especially as there was nothing to suggest that it would happen to begin with.